# Is getting User/Tenant Id in Data/Repository Layer bad practise?

Tags: c#, architecture, asp.net-identity

I was wondering what people thought on using DI to inject Microsoft identity into the data layer and then getting the users id from this. Is this a violation of SoC or just bad development practise?

For something I've developed I've had to do it as I don't want my data layer to reply on the services which would typically get the users identifier.

I will admit I'm not an expert on software architecture and this is how my solution is:

Data <- Services <- Website

Comment: Yes.  Extract the user/tenant id in your controller (probably from the HttpContext, or the ClaimsPrincipal) and use that to call services, mediator patter handler, whatever.  Then there is no need to have Identity in your service or data assembly.

Comment: You should consider posting that as an answer, Neil.

Answer (score 1):

As Neil said, passing identity values like UID allows you to remove dependencies from the downstream components, less dependencies makes for easier deployment, version control and dependency management in general.

It also means your downstream code is more easily testable because it's easier to run tests - you only have to pass the UID not construct an actual identity.

One reason you might want to have, say, the data access component get the UID itself is if you don't want it to be in a position where it has to trust the one passed to it.  Whilst that might be theoretically interesting, it's not a scenario I have ever actually seen "in the wild".